# Taurus & JMeter - ignore setup/teardown requests in reports

Tags: automated-testing, jmeter, performance, api-testing, performance-testing

I'm using Taurus to execute JMeter test files. In my JMeter files, I need to do a small amount of setup and teardown (for authentication purposes and data seeding). They aren't directly related to the application under test.

Is there anyway to ignore these threads in the output Taurus reports (in terms of contributions to average times etc.)?

I did see a similar question get asked in 2016 here - https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/codename-taurus/jZ9lrfCymFk but doesn't seem like any official resolution was reached.

If it's not possible to ignore these threads, do you have any suggestions on alternative solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to "ignore" them on JMeter level, just add [JSR223 PostProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor) as the child of the request(s) you want to ignore or if you want to ignore the whole Thread Group - put it at the same level as Samplers (see [JMeter Scoping Rules](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-scoping-rules-the-ultimate-guide/) for more details)

Use the following code to discard the sample result:

```
prev.setIgnore()
```

where **prev** is the shorthand for [SampleResult](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/samplers/SampleResult.html) class instance

The JSR223 PostProcessor will inform JMeter to not to consider the results of the Sampler(s) in its scope hence they won't appear in listeners, .jtl file and Taurus will not be able to count them

In general Taurus doesn't add any value, just overhead so if you don't use mix of tools or not defining your test scenarios in YAML - go for vanilla JMeter